NEXTJS, styling is not working in inner components
I am trying to make a chatgpt clone using nextjs and tailwind. I am working on the main chat screen, for each message I am using a message component with styling of its own however the styling is not being applied at all for the message component. I have tried multiple solutions but none of them are working.
chatpage.js
import Head from 'next/head';
import { ChatSidebar } from '@/components /ChatSidebar';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { streamReader } from 'openai-edge-stream';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { Message } from '@/components /Message';

export default function Home() {
  const [incomingMessage, setIncomingMessage] = useState('');
  const [messageText, setMessageText] = useState('');
  const [newChatMessages, setNewChatMessages] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setNewChatMessages(prev => {
      const newChatMessages = [
        ...prev,
        {
          _id: uuid(),
          role: 'user',
          content: messageText,
        },
      ];
      return newChatMessages;
    });
    console.log(messageText);
    const response = await fetch('/api/chat/sendMessage', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: messageText }),
    });
    const data = response.body;

    if (!data) {
      return;
    }

    const reader = data.getReader();
    await streamReader(reader, async message => {
      console.log('Message: ', message);
      setIncomingMessage(s => `${s}${message.content}`);
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>New Chat</title>
      </Head>
      <div className="grid h-screen grid-cols-[260px_1fr]">
        <ChatSidebar />
        <div className="flex flex-col bg-gray-700">
          <div className="flex-1 text-white">
            {newChatMessages.map(message => (
              <Message
                key={message._id}
                role={message.role}
                content={message.content}
              />
            ))}
            {!!incomingMessage && (
              <Message role="assistant" content={incomingMessage} />
            )}
          </div>
          <footer className="bg-gray-800 p-8">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <fieldset className="flex gap-2">
                <textarea
                  value={messageText}
                  onChange={e => setMessageText(e.target.value)}
                  placeholder="Send a message..."
                  className="w-full resize-none rounded-md bg-gray-700 px-5 py-1 text-white"
                ></textarea>
                <button className="btn" type="submit">
                  Send
                </button>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


message component js
import { useUser } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';
import Image from 'next/image';
export const Message = ({ role, content }) => {
  const { user } = useUser();
  return (
    <div
      className={`grid grid-cols-[30px_1fr] gap-5 p-5${
        role === 'assistant' ? ' bg-gray-600' : ''
      }`}
    >
      <div>
        {role === 'user' && !!user && (
          <Image
            src={user.picture}
            width={30}
            height={30}
            alt="User profile picture"
            className="rounded-sm shadow-md shadow-black/50"
          />
        )}
        {role === 'assistant' && <div>avatar</div>}
      </div>
      <div>{content}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

I am trying to make the message component styling work.

Did all styles in Message not applied or just the color?
BTW, if user is passed as a prop to Message would be better, cause every time you render a new Message will make a new user request.

@DaveLin None of the styling is getting applied in message.js and thanks for the suggestion for the user, let me apply that!

Update, for my other component chat sidebar the styling is not being applied "import Link from 'next/link';
export const ChatSidebar = () => {
return (

Logout

);
};
" only the text color styling is being applied which is weird

Found the mistake, its apparently there was a trailing whitespace in my components folder which was not there in tailwind.config.js, I removed the whitespace from the folder name and it worked. Tip: be careful about the names in your nextjs tailwind projects.
